# Returning structure pointer

Tags: c

I'm confused with [code](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-minimum-element-in-a-binary-search-tree/) below:

```
struct node* newNode(int data) 
{
  struct node* node = (struct node*)
                       malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  node->data  = data;
  node->left  = NULL;
  node->right = NULL;

  return(node);
}

struct node* insert(struct node* node, int data) 
{
  /* 1. If the tree is empty, return a new,     
      single node */
  if (node == NULL) 
    return(newNode(data));  
  else
  {
    /* 2. Otherwise, recur down the tree */
    if (data <= node->data) 
        node->left  = insert(node->left, data);
    else
        node->right = insert(node->right, data);

    /* return the (unchanged) node pointer */
    return node; 
  }
}
```

`newNode` returns a pointer to the structure it has allocated. However in line 6 of the `insert` function the return value of `newNode` is not being assigned to anything, it's just being called. How is the code further down able to use the newly created node structure?

Comment: The caller keeps track of the returned pointer.

Comment: I will include that in my answer @ThunderWiring, if you don't mind!

Comment: @gsamaras no problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the interesting part of recursion!

The result of `newNode` is assigned to either `node->left` or `node->right`.
Take this tree for instance:

```
    2
   / \
  1   NA
```

(note: NA = Not Available = NULL)

**Now you want to add 3:**

you pass to `insert` the root(i.e the node with key 2 above)
and then the function gets to this line `node->right = insert(node->right, data);` (try to understand why yourself!)

which calls to `insert` again with node NA
which eventually gets to the line `return(newNode(data));`
The returned result is assigned to node NA after the recursion back-tracks.

Eventually' you'll have this tree:

```
    2
   / \
  1   3
```

Answer (score 2):

Code below will run, if the tree is *NOT* empty. So, when the code in step .2 runs, the code in step .1 does not.

When the recursion unwinds, you can see that the assign operation is happening, for example:

```
node->left  = insert(node->left, data);
```

Oh and as ThunderWiring said, [do not cast malloc!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: Code will run even if the tree is empty: it just creates a new top level node.

Comment: Correct @SergeBallesta.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is an ordered tree.

You can create the tree by passing a NULL pointer, and you will get the top node. Next, when you add new items, they will be automatically inserted in correct place. But beware the structure of the tree will heavily depend on the insertion order.

If works, because on line 6 of `insert` function, the return value of `newNode`, is returned to caller. If node was initially NULL, it is expected that the programmer is creating a top node with something like:

```
struct node *top = insert(NULL, data);
```

So the return value of `newNode` will finally be assigned to pointer `top`.

When you insert a value in an existing tree, you will recurse down the tree until you find a node that has a NULL in its `left` (resp. `right`) field, and the newly created node will be assigned to that (previously NULL) field.